# Copy and Rename Files with batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have thousands of text files formatted something similar to `abcdefgh_20140430120000.txt`

I would like to copy those from one folder to another folder like

```
xcopy "Y:\FolderA" "C:\FolderB"
```

However, I want to remove the time portion in the file name so that the text file would look like `abcdefgh_20140430.txt`

Can anyone help me with code to do so?

Comment: Have you done any research into doing this yourself, like at least doing a search here? It doesn't appear you have, as `x copy` is not a valid command. Search SO for `[batch-file] copy rename files` (exactly as  I typed it, including the `[]` brackets, and see what you can find. Make an effort to do it yourself, and if you can't get it to work you can come back and ask a specific question about the problem you're having, include your effort, and we can try to help. You **do** need to make some effort yourself first, though. Good luck. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite, I have been looking for a solution.  xcopy is a command and it does work.  Sorry I left a space between "x" and "copy".  I also excluded the switches I am using while copying as it wasn't relevant.  I just need help in removing the last 6 characters of the file other than the .txt.  Ican handle an individual file doing something like 'ren %fName% %fName:~0,-6%.txt' but need some kind of loop.  Thanks for voting it down though

Comment: I see no sign of any effort, and the question has a clearly non-existent command (the `x copy` I mentioned). The search phrase I provided has many related questions; I've seen several here before asking the same question. (Also, be careful making accusations without evidence. A comment does not necessarily mean a downvote, any more than a downvote requires that a comment accompany it.)

Comment: xcopy is a command I have been using for years to move files withing a directory to another directory.  You can read about it here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true.

Comment: for "some kind of loop" see `for /?`

Comment: Are you sure, filenames are still unique after shortening them?

Comment: @stephan, the file names will still be unique after removing.  Two files are generated each day.  The first 9 characters are the report names (which are different) and an underscore while the last 8 are datetime.  I said remove the last 6 but I forgot there were 8 characters.  They look like this: RPT0261E_2014043001044592.txt.  They will be unique with just the report name and year month day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch this in the folder: it should copy them as you wish and remove the last 6 characters of the filename.

Filenames with `!` in them will generate an error.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d ') do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    copy "%%a" "C:\FolderB\!name:~0,-6!%%~xa" 
)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great!, now can I add something to delete the files with longer file names?

Comment: Launch it in the source folder.  `/b` gives a brief directory list (try the command `dir /b`) and the `/a-d` (attributes minus directory) removes folders from the list if they exist.

Comment: Open a new question for another task.  They are free. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the rename command to rid of the unwanted parts of the copied file name.

```
copy "Y:\FolderA" "C:\FolderB"
rename "C:\FolderB" "C:\FolderC"
```

That should work, if you have any problems then tell me and I'll try my best to fix it :)

You also do not need the x in front of copy, or at least I didn't need it since I'm using Windows 8.1, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Thanks @benimen.  I am successful in copying the text files in a folder from a shared network drive to my local drive which I do using xcopy.  The challenge I am having is that I am unable to shorten the file names by removing the last 6 characters for all the thousands of text files.

Comment: I had that problem too, I will try to fix it whenever I can :)

Answer (score -1):

```
COPY "C:PathOfFileToCopy\Filename" "C:PathOfCopyDestination\NewFilename"

RENAME "C:PathOfFileToCopy\Filename" NewFileName
```

Comment: There are already good answers. Adding a answer without a description and not even solving the problem should be avoided